# The application at <zip file> does not have a bundle identifier

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, xcode6

I'm trying to submit my app to FaceBook.

My Simulator build is at `DerivedData/*/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<app name>`.

So, from here I'm creating a zip file using the command :

```
ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent /Users/<user name>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<app name>.app <app name>.zip
```

But when I tried to run the zip file with the command :

```
ios-sim launch <app name>.zip
```

I get the following error :

> Session could not be started: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=22 "Installation Failed" UserInfo=0x7fed48e05830 {NSLocalizedDescription=Installation Failed, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The application at “/Users//.zip” does not have a bundle identifier}

Can we use the command `ios-sim launch <app name>.zip` to test the app?

How can we test the sim build before submitting it to the FB app store?

Also, can we use the build generated in Build from Debug-iphonesimulator folder to submit to FB app store or we have to use the Build from Release-iphonesimulator folder?

I'm very much new to iOS app development.

Answer (score 1):

You should unzip your file and try ./ios-sim launch xxx.app/